# Streamlit/leafmap not showing my color maps in app

Tags: python-3, leafmap, streamlit

I am trying to add some local .tif files to a Streamlit app, but when I assign the color bars my app in my local server is still in black and white.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import streamlit
import leafmap.foliumap as leafmap


col1 = st.columns(1)
col1[0].write("Comparison of Reference Data and Predicted Fire Locations")

m = leafmap.Map()
m.add_raster(selected_file, bands=[3], layer_name = 'dNBR', colormap='viridis')
m.add_raster(selected_file, bands=[1], layer_name = 'Reference Fire', colormap={0: 'gray', 1: 'red'})
m.add_raster(selected_file, bands = [2], layer_name = 'Predicted Fire', colormap={0: 'gray', 1: 'red'})
m.to_streamlit()
```

where `selected_file` is a three band raster on my computer.  The third band ranges from -1 to 1, while the 2nd and 3rd band are binary whereby 0 designates unburned pixels and 1 designates burned pixels.  Attached is an example of what `dNBR` looks like on my map.  As you can see it is still black and white, and not viridis. The same is true for the 1st and 2nd bands, they are also black and white.

[image]